# Sqlite .NET and Entity Framework - "attempt to write a readonly database"

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

---edit--- Is there any additional information I can give to help solve this problem?

I'm trying to get up and running with a Sqlite and Entity Framework within a .NET WCF web service.

When I try to save anything to the database, **I'm getting the error "attempt to write a readonly database"**. Here's the full error information:

> System.Data.EntityException: An error
>   occurred while starting a transaction
>   on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details.
>
> ---> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException:
>   Attempt to write a read-only database
>
> Attempt to write a readonly database
>   at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Reset(SQLiteStatement
>   stmt)
>   at  [snip]........................................................> 
>   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel
>   isolationLevel)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnection.BeginTransaction()
>   at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginTransaction()
>   at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(Boolean
>   acceptChangesDuringSave)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
>   at ...

Here's my EF configuration inside Web.config (with line breaks for easier reading):

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add 
      name="FooEntities" 
      connectionString="metadata=res://*/FooDataModel.csdl|
      res://*/FooDataModel.ssdl|
      res://*/FooDataModel.msl;
      provider=System.Data.SQLite;
      provider connection string='data source=C:\domains\myfoosite.com\wwwroot\FooService\Foo.sqlite'"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<connectionStrings>
```

Why am I receiving this error? Why is the database read-only?

Some things I've tried:

- Ensured the directory and file is
  write-able by the web service. (I've
  tried writing plain text files to the
  same directory as a test.)
- I've added the 'read only=False' to
  the connection string.

Comment: Does the user you're using to connect have write access to the database? Can you connect and write to the database using Management Studio (or equivalent)?

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not specifying credentials of any kind -- didn't specify Windows auth or Forms auth. I can connect and write to the database on my local machine, of course. I will try connecting on the web server.

Comment: From my understanding, Sqlite doesn't have Windows auth or Forms auth. It's just a single-file database, no services, no authentication. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the problem was IIS security settings. I had to turn on script write access, and magically it started working.

Comment: I've run into the same problem. Where did you turn "script write access" on? I looked in the handlers, but there I can choose between "write" and "script", but not both (radio buttons).

Comment: I figured it out. It's the Windows level write permission on the file system for the IIS user (IIS_IUSRS) which in my case could be configured via the hosts "WebsitePanel". Maybe it can also be configured via FTP (chmod) but I didn't try that.

Comment: @LouisSomers: You should add your comment as an answer to this question.